# Wordpressの投稿ページのURLを遷移した先の固定ページ内で使いたい

Tags: php, wordpress

はじめまして、よろしくお願いします。

Wordpressの投稿ページのURLを変数に入れて、その投稿ページ内のリンクから遷移した先の固定ページ内で「遷移元の投稿ページURL」を使いたいのですがうまく行きません。

投稿ページのsingle.phpで変数を定義して入れても、同じ変数名で固定ページで表示するとNULLと出てしまいます。

[single.php]

```
$url = get_permalink();
```

[kotei_test.php]

```
<?php
var_dump($url);
?>
```

変数のスコープあたりが間違ってるような気がするのですが、どこで設定すればいいのか分からず困惑してます。

Wordpressの変数の使い方の解説など参考になるページがあれば教えてもらえないでしょうか。

Wordpressカスタマイズ初心者で稚拙な質問ですいませんがよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

ページ遷移を行っている時点でそもそもPHPとして別のセッションなので変数はそもそも引き継がれません。

PHPとしてみると`$_SESSION`を使えばいい、と言うのが手っ取り早い話です、がWordPressでSESSIONを使うことは基本的に避けられています。

とはいえ、個人で使う分にはそれで十分かと思います。

single

```php
session_start();
$_SESSION['last_url'] = get_permalink();
```

page

```php
session_start();
if(!empty($_SESSION['last_url']) var_dump($_SESSION['last_url']);
```

@see
[[PHP] リクエストパラメータ・セッションに関するまとめ - Qiita # セッション関連あれこれ](http://qiita.com/mpyw/items/7852213f478e8c5a2802#%E3%82%BB%E3%83%83%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E9%96%A2%E9%80%A3%E3%81%82%E3%82%8C%E3%81%93%E3%82%8C)

P.S. ところでこのような動的な動作を必要とする場合キャッシュ等を利用すると意図せぬ動作を引き起こすことになるので注意してください。